# running the build action of web deployment project from final builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, finalbuilder, web-deployment-project

as you know Final builder is an outstanding build automation program, i want to use it, to automate moving the aspx, ascx, image files, css, dlls, etc... after the build of web deployment, this will ease so much the work for me instead of copying the file manually.

better yet how can i create a shortcut in visual studio so when i click it it will run the final build building process.

i think with this combination life will be much much easier and i will not have to go back and forth to do that.

so how can i do that ?

Comment: Are you using FinalBuilder Server? Or just FinalBuilder client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a mapped drive from your Build server to your live server then you can execute an XCOPY command in Final Builder to copy the files across.